# Can't replace attribute with field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, editing

I have an attribute table where one of the columns (laeskaerm) has been edited/created by checkboxes on 2 different machines.

**Result**: it contains both 1, 0, true, false and NULL

I'd like to replace 1 with true, and 0 with false. I've tried:

```
replace("laeskaerm",'1','true')
```

and

```
replace("laeskaerm",'1','true')
```

But I can't seem to make it work (QGIS 2.2.0).

**Do anyone have any idea whats wrong?**

Comment: What data type are your attributes?

Comment: As far as I can see, the field-type is set to Qstring, but I do not know wether it have been changed earlier

Comment: The second one,  you meant replace("laeskaerm",'0','false'), right?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following expression to **update** your "laeskaerm" field:

```
CASE WHEN "laeskaerm" = 1 THEN 'True' 
WHEN "laeskaerm" = 2 THEN 'False'
ELSE "laeskaerm"
END
```

Comment: I just tried this, but with no result. No changes were made in the column

Comment: @LarsPeter - Make sure you're editing mode before using the field calculator. If you were then perhaps your shapefile are read-only or protected?

Comment: I've had the same thought (made that error before) but that didn't seem to be the case this time.

BUT I tried 2 different editing plugins. The first crashed, the second one seems to be able to slove my problem. 

Thank you for your time

Comment: @LarsPeter - Awesome, glad you got it solved! You should post your solution as an **answer** so that others could benefit if they experience the same problem. Also, have you tried re-saving it as a new shapefile and then edit it using the field calculator?

Comment: funnily enough it didn't occur to me to resave and edit, probertly should have thought af that as one of the first things

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if("laeskaerm"='1' OR "laeskaerm"='true','true','false')
```

in 2.2

```
Case when "laeskaerm"='1' OR "laeskaerm"='true' then 'true'
Else 'false'
End
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to do so.

I recieve a syntax error (syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution

Instead of editing the fields myself I found a plugin that coould do the job (quickmultiattributeedit)

Thank you for your help and time